# Dartlang attach link to LIElement

Tags: dart

Is it possible to make LIElement into a link, and how can it be done?

I have tried

```
var li = new LIElement();
li.text = text;
li.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an anchor element, just like you would do it in HTML.

```dart
LIElement li = new LIElement();
AnchorElement a = new AnchorElement();
a.text = "I'm a <li> with an <a>!";
a.href = "http://www.google.com";
li.append(a);
```

Comment: Instead of using append(), I used children.add(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `href` setter on [LIElement](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/LIElement.html). Alternativly, you can add a listener on click to change the location of the page.

```dart
var li = new LIElement();
li.text = text;
li.onClick.listen((e) => window.location.assign("http://www.google.com"));
```